# Programmatically connect or detect to a certain WiFi in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi

In advance I am sorry for my English.

The task consists in defining, whether there is a person in a certain place (at certain office, for example), and to activate depending on it certain possibilities of the appendix.

At first I thought of definition of information on WiFi (or check of the same SSID, or automatic connection to the hidden network with set in the SSID appendix and the password), but, seemingly, not to make it without jailbreak (if somebody knows how - please, answer).
I think, GPS - not the best exit as it is possible to be out of the room, using it.

By the way, I already saw apps determining by WiFi of a point of access so it can be made somehow. I guess.

Actually, question. How it is better to define in the application, whether there is a device within, for example, premises of office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you know location coordinates you can safely use CoreLocation framework. Whether your target device supports region monitoring it will be perfect. It uses not only GPS, but WiFi and GSM as well
Look here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

If you really need to get network name you can play with `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` function of CaptiveNetwork framework.
See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Iam using Core location. But i am facing a situation here. I am, threatening to GPS spoofing. so is there any alternate way. I am really needy. Please help me.